# Android- Values Not inserted into database

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml

What i want is to pass name, username, password into mysql (phpmyadmin) database through android app. When i click register button it shows me a toast that registration success. But when i check into database no values are inserted, database still empty. I am not going to share my php scripts because they all are fine when i paste the url of all my php scripts. It works fine. But i will share on demand.

BackgroundTask.java

```
package com.example.abdul.mysqldbdemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx =ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url="http://zamin.byethost14.com/register.php";
    String login_url="http://zamin.byethost14.com/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result.equals("Registration Success..."))
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

Register.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Register extends Activity {
EditText ET_NAME,ET_USER_NAME,ET_USER_PASS;
String name,user_name,user_pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
     ET_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    ET_USER_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
    ET_USER_PASS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);

}
 public void userReg(View view)
{
name= ET_NAME.getText().toString();
user_name= ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
user_pass= ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
String method="register";
BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
finish();
 }


  }
```

activity_register.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#ffff7b57"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.abdul.mysqldbdemo.Register">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:textSize="40dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="#000"
android:text="Register Form"
/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="User Name"
    android:id="@+id/new_user_name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
   <EditText
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:id="@+id/new_user_pass"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:onClick="userReg"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

register.php

```
<?php
require"init.php";
$name=$_POST["user"];
$user_name=$_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass=$_POST["user_pass"];
$sql_query="insert into user_info   values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
{

echo"<h3>Data Insertion Success...</h3>";

}
else
{
echo "Data insertion error".mysqli_error($con);
}


?>
```

Comment: did you make a commit?

Comment: what did you said? i donot get you

Comment: something like $mysqli->commit()

Comment: In which file? I have 3 php files. init.php(about database connections), register.php(which i have shared above) and login.php.

Comment: register.php where you did the insert

Comment: $sql_query="insert into user_info     values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

Comment: @StefanBeike: here i insert above

Comment: exactly. and after that call commit

Comment: I have added. But still database is empty. Same situation

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method hope it helps.**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url="http://zamin.byethost14.com/register.php";
    String login_url="http://zamin.byethost14.com/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

              String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+"="+name,+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8")+"="+user_name+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8")+"="+user_pass;

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("login"))
    {
        String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = null
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);


            String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="login_name+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+login_pass;

             OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+= line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be many times better if you explained in words what makes it the answer.

Comment: @Akhil Ashok this code is not related to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution : encode the UTF characters that comes from app UI .

```
        username = URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
```